# grails layout nested pages

Tags: grails, gsp

I am trying to include one gsp into another but avoid the navbar that I have in the layout rendered twice. Below is my attempt to show this as briefly as possible.

main.gsp

```
...
<g:render template="dashboardNavbar"></g:render>
...
```

page1.gsp

```
...
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
...
```

page2.gsp

```
...
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<g:include action="page1"></g:include>
...
```

Page2 needs to be on its own so removing the meta tag is out of the question. I tried adding g:if block with a flag to control the rendering of the navbar template in main.gsp and pass that flag to the include directive as model but that causes both the navbars to disappear. Not sure why that happens. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you extract meta section from page1.gsp and save whole content as a separate template, which will be rendered either page1 or page2:

page1.gsp

```
...
<meta section for page1/>
<g:render template="contentDuplicatedInGsp1AndGsp2"></g:render>
...
```

page2.gsp

```
...
<meta section for page2/>
<g:render template="contentDuplicatedInGsp1AndGsp2"></g:render>
...
```

Of course remember to set apropriate variables in controller before rendering page2.gsp

Comment: Thanks @michal. I don't have different content to show. Its just that I want to avoid the display altogether since that header in meta tag is showing twice. I need both tags to show in their own pages but when one the I include one in another then only in the other one.

Comment: @AnupTripathi that's exactly what I have pseudocoded for you. Content for both pages is the same, only difference is their meta tags section.